# Computation of KO characteristic classes/numbers

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cobordism, characteristic-classes

How to compute KO characteristic classes/numbers?

They were introduced by Anderson/Brown/Peterson to study the structure of the spin cobordism ring. I looked through the literature but I did not find a nice example of computation. For instance, I would like to know how to determine $\pi^J(\mathbb{H}P^2)$. Many thanks for any comments in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Chapter II (in particular sections II.7 and II.9) of the book

Conner, P. E.; Floyd, E. E.
The relation of cobordism to K-theories. 
Lecture Notes in Mathematics, No. 28 Springer-Verlag, Berlin-New York 1966 v+112 pp.

gives a nice construction of $KO$-characteristic classes for symplectic bundles, in particular showing that they satisfy the usual axioms. From this you may be able to perform computations. I'm not sure what the notation $\pi^J$ means (cokernel of the J-homomorphism?).

Comment: I think $J$ denotes a multiindex $(j_i, \dots, j_k)$ and so $\pi^J(M) = \pi^{j_1}(M)\dots\pi^{j_k}(M)$ where $\pi^j(M)$ denotes the $j^{\text{th}}$ KO Pontryagin class.